# Adding a User Signup Workflow in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: postgresql, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-business-process

I am trying to add a user signup workflow in wso2 api manager through wso2-BPS.
I configured the steps exactly what given in [[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+a+User+Signup+Workflow). On my environment i have multiple tenants. I am able to Sign-Up a new user and once submitted i get 'Authentication required by administrator' as expected and when i login to https://localhost:9443/admin, I see the created user and waiting for 'Approval'. Once i approved in admin, i am expected to login to Store with that new user. But, Login failed. what could be the issue ? 
Additionally both wso2-bps and wso2-am should be point to same data-source ? My case both should be postgres ?

**Note: I am using Postgresql database.**

Comment: what is the error you see in logs?

Comment: Additionally, Does wso2-BPS & wso2-AM should be in same data sources ?

Comment: @Bhathiya, these are 3 lines recorded in wso2am log file

Comment: wso2carbon.log. TID: [-1234] [] [2017-01-26 10:20:28,405]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater} -  Permission cache updated for tenant -1234

Comment: {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-01-26 10:20:28,453]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  Failed Administrator login attempt 'testuser1[-1234]' at [2017-01-26 10:20:28,453-0600] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-01-26 10:20:28,455] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject} -  Login failed. Please recheck the username and password and try again. {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject}

Comment: Do you see any errors when approving?

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked about your own API Manager deployment, but if a hosted version is an option, you can consider [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud) (hosted version of WSO2 API Manager) that has user self-signup (with optional approvals, ability to customize UIs and emails, etc.) out of the box: https://docs.wso2.com/display/APICloud/Enable+Self+Sign-up+to+the+API+Store

Comment: thanks for reply !! unfortunately, i can not use cloud. I supposed to be on-premise.